# IE10 issue executing function after document open but before document write?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-10

So the relevant part of the code I am working on is something like this and it occurs within an iframe:

```
window.document.open();
alert("Opened document");
window.document.write("Hello World");
alert("Wrote to document");
window.document.close();
alert("Closed document");
```

This all works on FF and Chrome.  However, on IE 10, this silently fails after the window.document.open() line.  None of the alerts show up, nothing gets written to the blank iframe, and nothing throws an error on the IE10 debugger console.

If I remove the alert statements, everything works as it should.  But I need to run a function in between the opening and the writing of the document.

Anyone have any experience with this?  Thanks!

Comment: open() destroys the whole page, there's much better ways to inject content...

Comment: The content I need to write is a third party string of html.  It will contain scripts and possibly other html elements.  Using innerHTML won't execute the scripts.  AppendChild also doesn't seem to be an option seeing as I would have to do something like create a div element and set its innerHTML to the string which brings us back to the original innerHTML problem.

Comment: use jQuery and .html() instead of just .innerHTML if you want an easy way to fire off those scripts inline... you can also steal the script-tag finding regexp from prototype.js (a good rx), and eval() the text yourself... another route; i've re-defined document.write() to buffer and inject into the script's parent node with some success, depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're writing to an IFRAME. You can call this from IFRAME parent

```
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.open();
    alert("Opened document");
    document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.write("Hello World");
    alert("Wrote to document");
    document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.close();
    alert("Closed document");

</script>
```

Seems to work in IE as well.